# Spring annotation configuration does not find directories/classes in JARs

Tags: spring, maven-2, annotations

I have the same problem as these guys:

[Spring Annotation-based controllers not working if it is inside jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242656/spring-annotation-based-controllers-not-working-if-it-is-inside-jar-file)

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=64731

...but the difference is that I use Maven 2 as a build tool.

How do I achieve the same effect using Maven 2?

I saw this solution to creating a classpath entry in the manifest, but it generates a lot of absolute links to JARs which wouldn't make sense in my production environment:
[Maven - how can I add an arbitrary classpath entry to a jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510071/maven-how-can-i-add-an-arbitrary-classpath-entry-to-a-jar/1510543#1510543)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven 2 generates the directory entries, which is the answer to this question.