# How can I redirect to a controller that's in a library?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I have a Spring MVC `@Controller` in a library project which my main project depends upon. I want to redirect to this from a controller in my main project. How can I do this?

I have a `@Configuration` in the library with an appropriate `@ComponentScan`. I tried both putting that `@Configuration` in my `getServletConfigClasses()` in my main `ApplicationInitializer`, and putting it in an `@Import` tag on my main `@Configuration`.

When I do a return `"redirect:/whateverurl"` with either configuration, I just see the redirect string in my browser. It doesn't actually do the redirect.

Comment: *When I do a return `"redirect:/whateverurl"` with either configuration, I just see the redirect string in my browser. It doesn't actually do the redirect.* The application indeed **does** the redirect, but seems like Spring cannot manage the URL by using your `@Controller`, thus you get this issue. Make sure this `@Controller` is initialized and registered for use.

Comment: That's what I thought I was doing by annotating it with `@Controller`, making a `@Configuration` with appropriate `@ComponentScan`, then including that `@Configuration` in the two different ways I know of. Is there something more I need to do to register it?

Answer (score 0):

Is the library a Jar file?

If so, while creating the jar, the directory entries need to be added.

I think this question may have the answer -

[Auto-wiring annotations in classes from dependent jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936295/auto-wiring-annotations-in-classes-from-dependent-jars)

Thanks,
Paul