# Component Scan not finding @Component's in a JAR in Tomcat webapp

Tags: spring, web-applications, applicationcontext, opencms

I just filed a bug in the Spring bugsystem ( https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8551 ), but I am still unsure if I am missing something

I tracked down a problem with `<context:component-scan/>` to this statement.
Given the two following classes which are in the same JAR in WEB-INF/lib of a web application (The JAR file has the directory structure):

test/TheBean.java:

```
package test;
@Component
public class TheBean{
}
```

test/BeanSearcher.java:

```
package test;
public class BeanSearcher{

  public void init(){ 
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(); 
    ctx.scan("test"); 
    ctx.refresh(); 
    TheBean b=  ctx.getBean(TheBean.class); 
    // What is the value of b? 
  }
}
```

If I run `new BeanSearcher().init()` in a jUnit test case or other type of standalone application, b is getting assigned an instance of TheBean, but if I run it, say, in a JSP, `ctx.getBean()` is returning null.

So, am I doing something wrong or not taking something into account, is this just a bug...?

EDIT 8/8/2011: It seems to work good as I tried to simplify the problem, but still, when I try to make it work, in the initialization of OpenCms, it fails. Now I am trying to look for the differences between working versions and the one which doesn't work. (Classloader, ubication of the relevant classes in different JARs or directly in WEB-INF/classes, calls via reflection, etc.)

Comment: Are the Spring libraries in the webapp or are they installed directly into the Tomcat main lib dir? I've seen screwy problems when the latter is true…

Comment: The Spring libraries are as well in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: It could be related to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242656/spring-annotation-based-controllers-not-working-if-it-is-inside-jar-file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment, the solution is given by the answer here: 
[Spring Annotation-based controllers not working if it is inside jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242656/spring-annotation-based-controllers-not-working-if-it-is-inside-jar-file)

> When you export the jar file using the export utility in eclipse there
>   is a option called Add directory entries.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I dont know what what it does (Add directory entries), but  spring is now able to scan my components in linux enviroment!

Answer (score 2):

The obvious question is whether you have things like these in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/foo.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Without these, Spring won't actually load at all, let alone properly build beans…

Comment: I have, consciously, not added this configuration to the web.xml file as I expect everything to be capsuled in my JAR. As you can see, I am using an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` which does not require a context XML file. Or do I need it anyhow? Thanks!