# Spring is not able to load bean from a jar file

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a jar which defines a bean like:

```
@Component(value="SHTTP")
public class SHTTPImpl{
}
```

Inside the jar , i have another class which loads the above defined bean like:

```
public static xx getInstance() {
   getApplicationContext().getBean("SHTTP"); //Exception thrown here
}
```

where the function getApplicationContext() is defined as:

```
private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    if (appContext == null) {
        appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(XXContext.class);
    }
    return appContext;
}
```

Now, I added this jar file inside another project ,say "project B" which has its own xml application context. I have a class inside project B which tries to get the bean "SHTTPImpl" by calling function

> getInstance()

.

But, this doesnt seem to work as i get the org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'SHTTP' is defined

This problem occurs only when i run my testcase. IF i deploy my application in the server and run, the bean not found exception isnt happening. But, writing working testcase is important for me. So, please help me out

Thanks

EDIT : Here is my test case

```
@Test
public void testprocessRequestMessageType() throws Exception{
    ProcessIncomingTransactionsNoThreads processIncomingTransactionNoThreads = (ProcessIncomingTransactionsNoThreads)getBean("processTransactions");
    processIncomingTransactionNoThreads.processRequestMessageType(cm); //This method tries to load the bean from the jar file
}

public class BaseTest extends TestCase {
public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
    return new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/src/test/resources/test-service-context.xml");
}

public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
    return getContext().getBean(beanName);
}   
}
```

EDIT 2: 
I think it would be better to add how i define the root of my context in the jar file. Here is the content of

> XXContext.java file:

```
  @Configuration
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xxx.adapter.sms" }) //SHTTPImpl is in package com.xxx.adapter.sms.syn
  public class XXContext {
    @Bean
    ...
   }
```

The file test-service-context.xml in the project (this is not inside jar) defines a bunch of beans that isnt related to the issue in hand

**EDIT 3** Adding test-service-context.xml content (only relevant parts)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="processTransactions" class="com.XXX.batch.listener.ProcessIncomingTransactionsNoThreads" >
    <property name="batchDetailDAO" ref="batchDetailDAO"/>
    <property name="batchHeaderDAO" ref="batchHeaderDAO"/>
    <property name="batchTXDetailDAO" ref="batchTXDetailDAO"/>
    <property name="batchServiceUtil" ref="batchServiceUtil"/>
    <property name="batchMessageUtil" ref="batchMessageUtil"/>
</bean>

    <bean id="mBankingSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.XXX.batch.common.model.BatchControlParam</value>
            <value>com.XXX.batch.common.model.BatchDetail</value>
            <value>com.XXX.batch.common.model.BatchFileStatusLookup</value>
            <value>com.XXX.batch.common.model.BatchHeader</value>
            <value>com.XXX.batch.common.model.BatchPartnerPriority</value>
            <value>com.XXX.batch.common.model.BatchTXDetail</value>
            <value>com.XXX.batch.common.model.BatchTXStatusLookup</value>
            <value>com.XXX.batch.common.model.Party</value>
            <value>com.XXX.batch.common.model.PartyAttributes</value>
            <value>com.XXX.batch.common.model.PartyAttributeValues</value>
            <value>com.XXX.batch.common.model.PartyType</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Did you component-scan the package containing `SHTTPImpl`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, I did

Comment: Can you show your testcase? You might not be using the right configuration class/file.

Comment: It is very big, but i will add a part of it

Comment: can you post the content of test-service-context.xml?

Comment: test-service-context defines beans that arent related to the issue in hand. That is why i didnt post it

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242656/spring-annotation-based-controllers-not-working-if-it-is-inside-jar-file) may help you.

Comment: could you add your test-service-context.xml in your question ?

Comment: @willome Added the context file contents