# Spring @Controller Web Service from JAR in lib

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jar, libraries

I have created some web services with a library of code that I have imported into my Spring-based Java web project.

my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>serviceDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/config/*servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>serviceDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

My spring config:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="project.thc, global.libraries" />
```

My Service Controller:

```
package global.libraries.webservices;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import global.libraries.util.EntityUtil;

@Controller
public class THCWebServices {

    public static final String SOURCE_NAME = EntityUtil.Reflection.getClassName(new THCWebServices().getClass(), false);

    @RequestMapping(value=WebServicesConfig.ServiceUrl.userAuthenticationService, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String userAuthenticationService(@RequestParam String key, @RequestParam String project, @RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, HttpServletRequest request) {
        WebServiceResponse serviceResponse = new WebServiceResponse(project);
        WebServiceParameters serviceParameters = new WebServiceParameters(request, project, key);
        if (!serviceResponse.isMaintenance()) {
            serviceResponse.addMethodResult(WebServiceMethods.userAuthorizationService(serviceParameters));
        }
        return EntityUtil.convertToJson(serviceResponse, serviceParameters.getLogDirectory());
    }

}
```

Service URL:

```
WebServicesConfig.ServiceUrl.userAuthenticationService = "/authorization/validate";
```

I am using URL http://localhost:[port]/THC/services/authorization/validate and I keep getting 404 errors.

I have been unable to identify why the controller in the global library is not identified. Other services contained within the local project source load just fine.

**Is it possible to load web services into a project from a JAR (library)?**

**Can anyone see errors in my configuration that would prevent the service from being detected by the component scan?**

*EDIT NOTES: Added serviceDispatcher configuration from web.xml. Added reference for WebServicesConfig.ServiceUrl.userAuthenticationService. Updated example URL for localhost*

Comment: Please post your whole web.xml. Please show what servlet implementation serviceDispatcher maps to.

Comment: Can you add @Path for Controller and method and check if its accessible. Do you have any errors when you boot up the application?

Comment: Can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242656/spring-annotation-based-controllers-not-working-if-it-is-inside-jar-file? Maybe this can help you

Comment: What is the value for WebServicesConfig.ServiceUrl.userAuthenticationService , which u have mapped in ur controller ?

Comment: yes it is possible to register controllers from lib in spring, you need to properly configure your dispatcher servlet.

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking me with @Path. Reference? 
I updated my post to include the other requested information.

Comment: @DanielArechiga thank you! That link provided the answer! When generating the JAR that contains the controllers/services, you must check the "Add Directory Entries" checkbox (in Eclipse IDE). Doing this fixed the issue for me. http://i.imgur.com/RKPongG.png